# MongoDB query with elemMatch for nested array data

Tags: mongodb

I have a document containing nested array data. I tried hopelessly to filter the data using `$elemMatch` but I cannot figure out why it is not working.

```
{
'id' : 1,
'name' : 'test',
'modules' : [
    {
        name: 'foo',
        mandatory: false,
        group: [
            {
                name: g1
            }]
    },
    {
        name: 'bar',
        mandatory: false,
        group: [
            {
                name: g2
            }]
    }]
}
```

I tried using this query:

```
db.test.find(
{
  modules: {
            $elemMatch: {
                 name: "foo",
            }
  }
}
```

But it keeps returning all the modules. If I use `mandatory: true` it returns nothing, which seems to indicates it works. Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Querying is very easy but what about updates?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your query is simply returning all docs that contain a `modules` element where `name == 'foo'`.  To use [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch) to filter the output, you need to use it in the projection argument of the `find` call instead of part of the query:

```javascript
db.test.find({}, {modules: {$elemMatch: {name: 'foo'}}})
```

To combine both concepts, you can reference the index of the array element matched in the query with `$`:

```javascript
db.test.find({modules: {$elemMatch: {name: 'foo'}}}, {'modules.$': 1})
```

Either way returns:

```javascript
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "modules": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "mandatory": false,
      "group": [
        {
          "name": "g1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If you need other fields included in the output, add them to the projection object (e.g. `name: 1`).

Comment: Is it possible to chain the `elemMatch`? For example to filter on the "group" list on the name as well?