# Elem match is returning all the data whereas I need only the selected data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

```
db.mdb.collection('product_master').find({'project_code':'usha-fos', 'product_details' : {$elemMatch:{'Division':'Electric Fans'}}})
                .limit(1000,function(err,results){
                    if(!err){
                        //console.log("projection succeeded");
                       //console.log("its working");
                       //console.log(results);

                        if(results.length==0){
                            console.log("length is 0")
                        }
                        app.send(req,res,results);//this will send the appropriate data to my controller
                    }
                    else{
                        //console.log("it is throwing an error")
                    }
                })
```

And my data in JSON format is as follows:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57df7f5ab7079b1ab4d8a7dc"), 
    "agency_code" : "v5global", 
    "client_code" : "USHA_FOS", 
    "project_code" : "usha-fos", 
    "product_details" : [
        {
            "Division" : "Anything", 
            "Category" : "Ceiling Fans", 
            "Subcategory1" : "CF - UNIVERSAL - SMART", 
            "Subcategory2" : "STELLA", 
            "SKU" : "1200MM STELLA WH CF", 
            "SKU_Code" : "111048511", 
            "Description" : "", 
            "is_active" : "true"
        }, 
        {
            "Division" : "Electric Fans", 
            "Category" : "Ceiling Fans", 
            "Subcategory1" : "CF - ADMIRE - UNDER LIGHT", 
            "Subcategory2" : "FONTANA", 
            "SKU" : "1280MM FONTANA ORCHID GOLD IVORY CF", 
            "SKU_Code" : "111055447", 
            "Description" : "", 
            "is_active" : "true"
        }, 
        {
            "Division" : "AC&R", 
            "Category" : "Ceiling Fans", 
            "Subcategory1" : "CF - ADMIRE - UNDER LIGHT", 
            "Subcategory2" : "FONTANA", 
            "SKU" : "1250MM FONTANA MAPLE ANTIQUE BRASS CF", 
            "SKU_Code" : "111055448", 
            "Description" : "", 
            "is_active" : "true"
        }, 
        {
            "Division" : "Electric Fans", 
            "Category" : "Ceiling Fans", 
            "Subcategory1" : "CF - ADMIRE - UNDER LIGHT", 
            "Subcategory2" : "FONTANA", 
            "SKU" : "1230MM FONTANA LOTUS BLK CHROME CF", 
            "SKU_Code" : "111056414", 
            "Description" : "", 
            "is_active" : "true"
        }, 
        {
            "Division" : "Home Comfort", 
            "Category" : "Ceiling Fans", 
            "Subcategory1" : "CF - ADMIRE - UNDER LIGHT", 
            "Subcategory2" : "FONTANA", 
            "SKU" : "1230MM FONTANA LOTUS STEEL CF", 
            "SKU_Code" : "111056430", 
            "Description" : "", 
            "is_active" : "true"
        }
]}
```

/*   I want the data whose division is electric fans but I am getting all the data irrespective of the division.
Please help me out */
/*Thanks in advance.*/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB query with elemMatch for nested array data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525754/mongodb-query-with-elemmatch-for-nested-array-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[$elemmatch(query)](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)*** returns all rows in a array when there is atleast one row matching the query criteria.

***[$elemMatch(projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)*** returns only the first row of all the matching rows when used as projection.

You can easily get all matching rows by using array aggregation operator ***[$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)***.

In this scenario, product details will be filtered based on the crtieria passed.

```
aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "project_code": 'usha-fos'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "agency_code": 1,
        "client_code": 1,
        "project_code": 1,
        "product_details": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$product_details",
                "as": "result",
                cond: {
                    $eq: ["$$result.Division", "Electric Fans"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```