# Mongoose get only objects from array matching element inside the object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to obtain the objects inside the `reviews` array by matching the `fb_id`'s that I'm passing. I do not seem to get them to work. This is my actual document in the DB

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5841d18187dcc74805887a6a"
    },
    "product_id": "583ae172231f5ec01db5727e",
    "category": "Smartphones",
    "reviews": [
        {
            "fb_id": "111",
            "name": "name1",
            "user_img": "imgurl1",
            "title": "asdakj",
            "description": "jnkjnkj",
            "rating": 5,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5841d18187dcc74805887a6b"
            }
        },
        {
            "fb_id": "222",
            "name": "name2",
            "user_img": "imgurl2",
            "title": "dadad",
            "description": "asdasdad",
            "rating": 3,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5841d1d0cbdf333411530ebd"
            }
        },
        {
            "fb_id": "333",
            "name": "name3",
            "user_img": "img url3",
            "title": "asdad",
            "description": "asdads",
            "rating": 5,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5841d4c2174270f807084721"
            }
        },
        {
            "fb_id": "444",
            "name": "name4",
            "user_img": "imgurl4",
            "title": "adasd",
            "description": "kjnkj",
            "rating": 1,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5841d569eae1b6600ea1ca92"
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

I will be sending an array of `fb_id`'s to mongoose and want the results only for the objects inside the array that has the `fb_id`'s.

This is my query now:

```
Review.find({ product_id: '583ae172231f5ec01db5727e' }, { 'reviews.$.fb_id': { $in: <array of fb_id> } }, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    };
    console.log(results)

});
```

But it gives me this error :

```
MongoError: Unsupported projection option: reviews.$.fb_id: { $in: [ 111.0 ] }
```

**EDIT:** After a small query, now I am to get some results. But the result has only the first object that match from the `fb_id`'s and not all.

Please tell me how I can achieve this.

Comment: Please take a look at this one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40932617/2683814. Basically you to use $filter aggregator operator to return all matching records for a given criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for [reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents).
your code would be something like this:

```
Review.find({
    product_id: '583ae172231f5ec01db5727e'
    },
    {
        reviews: {
            $elemMatch: {
                fb_id: {
                    $in: <array of fb_id>
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        _id: 0,
        'reviews.$': 1
    }
, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    };
    console.log(results)
});
```

Comment: this returns only the first item that matches from the array. It does not return all the items that match

Comment: maybe its because of `product_id`! it's supposed to be unique?!

Comment: Yes product ID is unique. And I want the reviews matching fb Id's only for that product ID.